# make exits with error due to a special character in the filename

Tags: makefile, aix

We're generating make files for our source files and one of these files happens to have a '#' in its name. 
The dependency statement in the make file looks like this:

```
./obj/abc/def#ghi.o: ./src/abc/def#ghi.pli
    ...
```

Which results in error:

```
Zeile 15: make: 1254-055 Abhängigkeitszeilen erfordern einen Doppelpunkt oder doppelten Doppelpunkt als Operator.
```

I tried to escape the '#' but neither single quotes, double quotes, one backslash or 2 backslashes work. Is there a way to fix this without renaming the file?

Comment: # is used for commenting and it can't be quoted. I think you're out of luck here.

Comment: One backslash works for me (GNUMake 3.81). Which version of Make do you use?

Comment: @Beta
I'm using AIX make. (Not sure, which version).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're out of luck, especially with the AIX version of make.

The AIX Make documentation is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds3%2Fmake.htm), and doesn't mention any way of escaping the `#` character.

The GNU Make documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) mentions that it's possible:

> If you want a literal #, escape it with a backslash (e.g., \#). 
>   Comments may appear on any line in the makefile, although they 
>   are treated specially in certain situations.

Is there any reason that you can't build GNU Make for AIX and use it instead of the AIX make?